# Mocking contains() with a String[][]

Tags: java

I have two SQL tables. After grabbing both tables in `ResultSets`, I've stored them in `String[][]s`, ordered by a common id column. These tables should contain the same data, however one may have duplicates of the same row from the other. In order to check if every `String[]` in table A is present at least once in table B, I need to construct a somewhat efficient `contains()`-esque method for `String[]`.

This is what I have so far, but am stumped (also not sure if there's  a much more efficient solution). Give it the source table and target table. It takes each `String[]` in the source table and (should) go through each `String[]` in the target table and find an instance of the source `String[]` somewhere in the target `String[][]` by checking if there's at least one `String[]` that matches the original `String[]`, element by element. Can anyone point me in the right direction and/or fill in the blanks? This isn't homework or any assignment, I'm refactoring some code and am having a major brain fart. Thanks!

```
    public boolean targetContainsSource(String[][] s, String[][] t) {
    boolean result = true;

    //For each String[] in String[][] s
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

        //For each String[] in String[][] t
        for (int j = 0; j < t.length; j++) {

            //For each String in t's String[]
            for (int k = 0; k < t[0].length; k++) {
                if (!s[i][k].equals(t[j][k])) {

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your innermost loop could be removed by using [Arrays.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).

For each element of the first array, you should define a `found` boolean variable, that would only be set to true once the element is found in the second array. Once the second loop is finished, if this variable is still false, you have found an element of the first array that is not in the second, and you can return immediately.

And of course, as soon as this variable is set to true, you can break out of the second loop.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of booleans but just couldn't get my thoughts into a working algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you generally need to do the following:

- use a strong hash function to **take a hash** of each row: this gives you a single integer (probably a long to be strong enough) or single string/byte array representing the entire row
- then proceed as though you were comparing two "lists" of rows. At least one of these "lists" should actually be stored in a HashSet/HashMap, whose contains() method is efficient.

For the hash function you could use MD5 (e.g. you can [use this code](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/hash_functions_algorithms.shtml), but use "MD5" instead of "SHA-1"). You can use MessageDigest.compare() to compare to byte arrays representing hash codes.

If you only have a small number (say, a few tens of thousands) of rows, then you could [use a 64-bit hash code](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/strong_hash_code_implementation.shtml)-- this just has the advantage that each hash is stored in a long so they're a bit easier to shufty about and compare. But 64-bit hash codes are only strong enough for guaranteeing uniqueness of hashes of tens to hundreds of thousands of objects (=different rows in your case).

P.S. If you're prepared to store all of the data in memory, then you could also just use as the "hash" of each row all of the columns concetenated together into a single string. The trick is to make the check efficient to have one of the tables' row representations stored in a HashSet/HashMap.